# Web Api 2 Attribute Routing and Angular JS params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

So if I have this controller action:

```
[Route("{id:int}")]
public async Task<JsonResponse> GetAsync(int id)
{
}
```

Sending data to it from Angular, like this:

```
$http.get('/api/someController', { params: { id: someId } });
```

Doesn't cut it. It needs to have the URL generated to look like this:

```
/api/someController/someId
```

I would like to retain this Web API 2 feature, so how do I get Angular to build my URL differently?

Apart from the obvious:

```
$http.get('api/someController/' + someId);
```

If it has to be done the above way, I don't mind. However, I'm just wondering if someone has a solution for this? That isn't overly complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented exactly what you are talking about by doing just what you mentioned:

```
$http.get('api/someController/' + someId);
```

I couldn't find a better way to do it and it seemed quite simple.

Comment: Interesting, I might read down into the Angular Docs, see what I can come up with

Comment: I have typically used the restangular library (https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) to interact with WebAPI services and would definitely suggest it to you.